# Purpose of complementary function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that adding the complementary function with the particular integral provides a valid general solution given by the proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3kHo.png).

However, I don't quite understand why the complementary function is necessary. In my shallow understanding, we are adding on the complementary function simply to give the solution more detail with the rationale 'the more the merrier'.

I'm new to differential equations and only understand that we are trying to find a $y(x)$ that satisfies the differential equation. And the particular solution has done that already.

Comment: You don’t just want to find *one* function which satisfies the ODE; often we want to find them all. So there is the question of uniqueness. Suppose $y_1,y_2$ satisfy $L[y_1]=f$ and $L[y_2]=f$. Does that automatically imply $y_1=y_2$? No. All that implies is that $L[y_1-y_2]=0$, i.e $y_1-y_2$ satisfies the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @peek-a-boo's description is accurate, but let me add that when you start trying to fit boundary conditions and initial conditions, the complementary solutions become essential.

Comment: Right. There are a lot of functions that satisfy, say, $y'=y$, but only one of them also satisfies $y'(0)=17$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay, so there is more than one solution. I must've overlooked that. My understanding now is that the complementary function gives room for more than one solution, since it often if not always contains arbitrary constants (correct me if I'm wrong but they originate from the constants of integration). Since we want as many solutions as possible, we include the complementary function. This is my loose understanding atm. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yup that’s roughly the gist of it, but to be a little more explicit, there’s the slight issue (which I should have phrased better in my previous comment, but fortunately others have said already) that our goal isn’t really that “we want as many solutions as possible”, but rather we want solutions with such and such property (e.g initial or boundary conditions). If we ignore solutions of the homogeneous equation, then we can’t always satisfy these properties.

Comment: So just to get things straight: There will be arbitrary constants involved when solving ODE's. And we need initial conditions to get those unknowns. But in order to fit those arbitrary constants in the general solution in the first place, we need to use the complementary function.

Comment: You''re definitely closer. But "they originate from constants of integration" isn't really right. And you're not helped by that slide saying "__the__ complementary function". There is usually a whole vector space of complementary functions. Assuming $L$ is a linear operator, then if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ satisfy $L[y] = 0$ then so does $ay_1(x) + by_2(x)$, for any constants $a,b$. And instead of " we need initial conditions to get those unknowns" the thinking is more like "finding appropriate values of these arbitrary constants let us satisfy the specified initial conditions."

Comment: The math might be the same, but the emphasis is different. Finding specific values for those constants is not the priority, satisfying the initial or boundary conditions of the stated problems is. And finding the entire family of solutions (parameterized by the arb. constants) is what allows us to satisfy them - or (sometimes) to be able to definitively say that no such solution exists.

Comment: @JonathanZ, if not the constants of integration then where do the arbitrary constants in the CF come from? I did a few examples and saw that I turned the +C into the arbitrary constants — 'But "they originate from constants of integration" isn't really right'.

Comment: You can get some arbitrary constants via integration, and when you write "$+C$" that's probably where they come from. But consider this: If your equation is $\dot y - y =0$, then $y(x) = e^x$ is one complimentary solution, but in fact $y(x) = C_1 e^x$ is also a solution for any $C_1$. And this arb. const. comes from the linear nature of $L[y] = \dot y - y$.